# Change "JPanel" on doubleclick in JTable with populated data

Tags: java, swing, jtable, layout-manager, cardlayout

I am making simple CRUD app in Java and I would like to create *"detail view"* for result which user choose. I have a simple code, that can create records and populate them into the table using JDBC. Now I want to make that if user choose one record with double click on row in JTable he shoud see something like detail view for the result.

Class Customer.java

```
package customereditor;


public class Customer {

    private int Id;
    private String name;
    private String surname;

    public int getID() {
        return Id;
    }

    public void setId(int Id) {
        this.Id = Id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getSurname() {
        return surname;
    }

    public void setSurname(String surname) {
        this.surname = surname;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" + "ID=" + Id + ", name=" + name + ", surname=" + surname + '}';
    }

}
```

Class CustomerDao.java

```
package customereditor;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.ResultSetMetaData;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class CustomerDao {

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/CustomerEditorDb");
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return conn;
    }

    public static List<Customer> getAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> allCustomers = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CE_CUSTOMERS");
            while (rs.next()) {
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                customer.setName(rs.getString(2));
                customer.setSurname(rs.getString(3));
                allCustomers.add(customer);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return allCustomers;
    }

    public static List<String> getColumnNames() {
        List<String> columnNames = new ArrayList();
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM CE_CUSTOMERS");
            ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
            int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();
            for (int i = 1; i <= columnCount; i++) {
                String columnName = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
                columnNames.add(columnName);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return columnNames;
    }

    public static void createCustomer(Customer customer) {
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO CE_CUSTOMERS(ID, NAME, SURNAME) VALUES (?,?,?)");
            pstmt.setInt(1, customer.getID());
            pstmt.setString(2, customer.getName());
            pstmt.setString(3, customer.getSurname());
            pstmt.execute();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    public static Customer getCustomerById(int customerId) {
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM CE_CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=?");
            pstmt.setInt(1, customerId);
            ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                customer.setId(rs.getInt(1));
                customer.setName(rs.getString(2));
                customer.setSurname(rs.getString(3));
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return customer;
    }

    public static void deleteCustomer(int customerId) {
        try {
            Connection conn = getConnection();
            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM CE_CUSTOMERS WHERE ID=?");
            pstmt.setInt(1, customerId);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(CustomerDao.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


}
```

Class DataTableModel.java

```
package customereditor;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;

public class DataTableModel extends AbstractTableModel {

    private final Map<Integer, Boolean> checkBoxes;
    private final List<String> columnNames;
    private final List<Customer> allCustomers;

    public DataTableModel() {
        this.checkBoxes = new HashMap<>();
        this.columnNames = CustomerDao.getColumnNames();
        this.allCustomers = CustomerDao.getAllCustomers();
    }

    public void addRow(Customer customer) {
        allCustomers.add(customer);
        fireTableRowsInserted(allCustomers.size() - 1, allCustomers.size() - 1);
    }

    public void removeRow(int rowIndex) {
        allCustomers.remove(rowIndex);
        fireTableRowsDeleted(rowIndex, rowIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public String getColumnName(int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex > 0) {
            return columnNames.get(columnIndex - 1);
        } else {
            return "#";
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return allCustomers.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return columnNames.size() + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Customer customer = allCustomers.get(rowIndex);
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                Object value = checkBoxes.get(rowIndex);
                return (value == null) ? Boolean.FALSE : value;
            case 1:
                return customer.getID();
            case 2:
                return customer.getName();
            case 3:
                return customer.getSurname();
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex > 0) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex > 0) {
            Customer customer = allCustomers.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 1:
                    customer.setId((int) value);
                case 2:
                    customer.setName((String) value);
                case 3:
                    customer.setSurname((String) value);
            }
        } else {
            checkBoxes.put(rowIndex, (boolean) value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Class getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                return Boolean.class;
            case 1:
                return Integer.class;
            case 2:
                return String.class;
            case 3:
                return String.class;
            default:
                return String.class;

        }

    }

}
```

Class CustomerEditorMain.java

```
package customereditor;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CustomerEditorMain {

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TableDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        CustomerView view = new CustomerView();
        frame.add(view);

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {        

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

- Class Customer.java  is simple POJO.
- Class CustomerDao.java works with derby DB.
- Class DataTableModel.java is a model for JTable in CustomerView.java. This model uses three collection frameworks. One  for adding checkboxes to delete only selected rows. Other are used to store column names and data from JDBC.
- Class CustomerEditorMain.java just run program.
- And Class **CustomerView.java** contain swing components. Here I want make something like detail view for record in table. I can do here simple method called detailCustomerViewPanel that returns JPanel. This method needs customerId. This customerId is selected from selected row in JTable. After user press double click on row also JPanel is changed.

Class CustomerView.java

```
package customereditor;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CustomerView extends JPanel {

    private final CardLayout cardLayout;
    private final JPanel cards;
    private final DataTableModel dataModel;
    private final JTable table;

    public CustomerView() {
        this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
        this.cards = new JPanel(cardLayout);
        this.dataModel = new DataTableModel();
        this.table = new JTable(dataModel);
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(createButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        cards.add(createShowAllCustomersPanel(), "createShowAllCustomersPanel");
        cards.add(createNewCustomerPanel(), "createNewCustomerPanel");
        add(cards, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    private JPanel createButtonsPanel() {
        JPanel buttonsPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        JButton createNewCustomer = new JButton("New");
        createNewCustomer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cards, "createNewCustomerPanel");
            }
        });
        buttonsPanel.add(createNewCustomer);
        JButton deleteCustomer = new JButton("Delete");
        deleteCustomer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                for (int i = dataModel.getRowCount() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    boolean checked = (boolean) dataModel.getValueAt(i, 0);
                    if (checked) {
                        CustomerDao.deleteCustomer((int) dataModel.getValueAt(i, 1));
                        dataModel.removeRow(i);
                        dataModel.setValueAt(Boolean.FALSE, i, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        buttonsPanel.add(deleteCustomer);
        return buttonsPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createShowAllCustomersPanel() {
        JPanel createShowAllCustomersPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
                    // get ID value from selected row and "first" column
                    int getCustomerId = (int) table.getValueAt(table.getSelectedRow(), 1);
                    // create JPanel and add to cards
                    cards.add(detailCustomerViewPanel(getCustomerId), "detailCustomerViewPanel");
                    cardLayout.show(cards, "detailCustomerViewPanel");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {

            }

            @Override
            public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {

            }
        });
        JScrollPane paneTable = new JScrollPane(table);
        createShowAllCustomersPanel.add(paneTable);
        return createShowAllCustomersPanel;
    }

    private JPanel createNewCustomerPanel() {
        JPanel createNewCustomerPanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Id:");
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(idLabel);
        JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(idField);
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(nameLabel);
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(nameField);
        JLabel surnameLabel = new JLabel("Surname:");
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(surnameLabel);
        JTextField surnameField = new JTextField(10);
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(surnameField);
        JButton saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                if (idField.getText() != "") {
                    Customer customer = new Customer();
                    customer.setId(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()));
                    customer.setName(nameField.getText());
                    customer.setSurname(surnameField.getText());
                    CustomerDao.createCustomer(customer);
                    dataModel.addRow(customer);
                }
            }
        });
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(saveButton);
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cards, "createShowAllCustomersPanel");
            }
        });
        createNewCustomerPanel.add(closeButton);
        return createNewCustomerPanel;
    }

    private JPanel detailCustomerViewPanel(int customerId) {
        JPanel detailCustomerViewPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        // get customer by ID
        Customer customer = CustomerDao.getCustomerById(customerId);
        JLabel idLabel = new JLabel("Id:");
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(idLabel);
        JTextField idField = new JTextField(10);
        idField.setText(Integer.toString(customer.getID()));
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(idField);
        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel("Name:");
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(nameLabel);
        JTextField nameField = new JTextField(10);
        nameField.setText(customer.getName());
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(nameField);
        JLabel surnameLabel = new JLabel("Surname:");
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(surnameLabel);
        JTextField surnameField = new JTextField(10);
        surnameField.setText(customer.getSurname());
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(surnameField);
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        closeButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                cardLayout.show(cards, "createShowAllCustomersPanel");
            }
        });
        detailCustomerViewPanel.add(closeButton);
        return detailCustomerViewPanel;
    }

}
```

So my question is: Is there better way to do this?

Comment: [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) may be worth a look.

Comment: I have looked at it. But I really can not imagine how to use it. A short example will really help me. Thank you.

Comment: Try adding the [example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to you program.